# VBA regular expression containing commas, dashes and alphanumeric characters

Tags: regex, vba, excel, regex-lookarounds

I'm struggling a bit with a regular expression in VBA containing the following characters. I would like commas, dashes and alphanumeric characters.

I've got the alphanumeric characters figured out, but dashes and commas seem to be giving me trouble.

This is the function I've created

```
   Private Function StripSpecialCharacters(ByVal strField As String) As String

   Dim ObjRegex As Object   
   Set ObjRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
   With ObjRegex
     .Global = True
     .Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+" 'regular expression needs to contain commas and dashes
     StripSpecialCharacters = .Replace(Replace(strField, "-", Chr(32)), vbNullString)
   End With

   End Function
```

Can anyone help me out?

**UPDATE:**
Ok, I've been thinking a bit backwards. Sorry about that.

This is what I'm getting from my strField

```
Consult Hond's + Huid & Darm-AllergieÃ«ndieet Mix3.5 * 4 kg 8713112002917
```

I need to be able to strip all the special , strange characters from this string such as +, Ã« , *, . , ', & etcetera. Some special characters need to be replaced with a dash. These are the following ; spaces, + , / , &. 
At first I figured I'm going to replace the special characters and then use my regex. But any improvements are more then welcome. So to take the string I just gave. The end result should be like this.

`consult-honds-huid-darm-allergiedieet-mix3,5x4kg8713112002917` ( as you can see the dot has been replaced by a comma).

Comment: what is the purpose of your function ? you want to replace the speical characters ? with what?

Comment: `.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]+"` will match 1 or more chars other than ASCII letters and digits. No idea what you really need, perhaps, add the `,-` at the end of the character class *if you do not want to replace them*, i.e. `.Pattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9,-]+"`?

Comment: Can you see if escaping the commas and dashes works in your `.Pattern`? So `"[a-zA-Z0-9\,\-]+"`.

Comment: @MattCremeens These comma and hyphen need no escaping in your `"[a-zA-Z0-9\,\-]+"` pattern since a `,` is not special, and `-` is at the end of the character class.

Comment: If you need dashes, what is the purpose of `Replace(strField, "-", Chr(32)`?

Comment: Then I'm going with @WiktorStribiżew 's response.

Comment: Actually, I am not quite sure what OP needs. Kyuzo, please provide sample string containing all the chars you need to match and an expected output string. *dashes and commas seem to be giving me trouble* is not a clear problem statement.

Comment: @All let me update and give you guys more information.

Comment: Sorry, I think your question is unclear now.

Comment: @Wiktor what do you find unclear?   Summary : Consult Hond's + Huid & Darm-AllergieÃ«ndieet Mix3.5 * 4 kg 8713112002917 needs to be stripped to this : consult-honds-huid-darm-allergiedieet-mix3,5x4kg8713112002917   btw thanks for your help either way.

Comment: How come `x` is a special char? Why do you remove some special chars, and keep others?

Comment: x is not a special char sorry if that was unclear I just need to replace * with an x

Comment: It seems that "[^a-zA-Z0-9,-]+ almost works unfortunately the dash- doesn't

Comment: If understand you correctly, you want to replace `; space + / &` with `-`, `.` with `,`, `*` with `x` and remove every other special character. It is a bit complex what you are trying to achieve with just one regexp. I'm not sure that is even possible.

Comment: @Victor I want to replace space + / & with a -. That is correct. The . with and the * with x and remove every other special character. I understand it is a bit complex that is why I did a simple replace before putting the string through the regex ( at least I'm doing this at the moment ). Replace(strField, "+", "-")  etc. After this has been done to strField than I will use the regex. Hope this explain it a bit.

Comment: In that case, it seems [sln's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38773191/6352151) would suit your needs

Comment: Where the `strField` value was get from? Seems a UTF-8 source was processed as an ASCII string by decoding mistake, and should be fixed first. `Ã«` is represented in [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) by 2 bytes 0xC3 0xAB (11000011 10101011), that corresponds to [2-byte (110xxxxx 10xxxxxx) UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description) char `ë`.

Comment: @Victor so it seems. Thanks for your input.   Also thank to Wiktor , Matt, Shai and Comintern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Follow these steps:*

Input  `Consult Hond's + Huid & Darm-AllergieÃ«ndieet Mix3.5 * 4 kg 8713112002917`

```
       --------------------------|-------------------------
      | Find                     |   Replace
       --------------------------|-------------------------
1     | [\s\x7f-\xff'+/&]+       |   nothing
2     | [.]+                     |   ,
3     | [*]+                     |   x
4     | (?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])      |   -
       --------------------------|-------------------------

5     Conveert string to lower case
```

Output  `consult-honds-huid-darm-allergiedieet-mix3,5x4kg8713112002917`

Comment: I'm just curious and willing to learn here, but as per your answer you are suggesting OP to define 4 patterns for the regex (one at a time) and 4 replaces. Is that it? This could even be done using an array of patterns and performing the steps in a For loop, right?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the development machine at the moment but I'm going to think and try this as well. Thanks.

Comment: Ok , sweet I tested this in a VB.net enviroment and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Kyuzo I get `...-allergiendieet-...` instead of `...-allergiedieet-...`, am I missing something?

Comment: @omegastripes that is correct you should get allergiendieet.  I'm guessing sln made a small typo.